# Lightbox wont trigger actions

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Currently using rnrf for navigation. a button on lightbox was not able to trigger the onpress actions to go to another scene. help me please. This is how set up my rnrf

```
<Router>
<Lightbox key="lightbox">
    <Modal hideNavBar>
        <Scene drawer key='root' contentComponent={DrawerContent}>
            <Scene key='root'>
                <Scene hideNavBar key='Home' component={Screen.Home} />
                <Scene hideNavBar key='Details' component={Screen.Details} />
            </Scene>
        </Scene>
        <Scene hideNavBar key='Modals' component={Screen.Modals} />
    </Modal>
    <Scene key="LightBox" component={Component.LightBox} />
    <Scene key="MoreOptions" component={Component.MoreOptions} />
</Lightbox>
```

Here is the button on the lightbox

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { Actions.Home(); }}>
            <View>
                <Text style={s.text}>Group</Text>
            </View>
 </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

do note the button was working if set up like this but was not able to pass props through rnrf

```
<Router>
<Lightbox key="lightbox">
    <Modal hideNavBar>
        <Scene drawer key='root' contentComponent={DrawerContent}>
                <Scene hideNavBar key='Home' component={Screen.Home} />
                <Scene hideNavBar key='Details' component={Screen.Details} />
        </Scene>
        <Scene hideNavBar key='Modals' component={Screen.Modals} />
    </Modal>
    <Scene key="LightBox" component={Component.LightBox} />
    <Scene key="MoreOptions" component={Component.MoreOptions} />
</Lightbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important for you to understand that RNRF works following the hierarchy of the router tree...

In your context, you have:

```
<Scene key="LightBox"...
```

In parallel with the children of

```
<Modal...
```

When you perform an Actions.Home() , this will not do anything because you cannot "jump" in parallel. In order to archive it, you will need to do something like...

In the page that call the LightBox:

```
 const callback = () =>{
    Actions.Home()
 }
 Actions.MyLightBox({callback})
```

In your Lightbox:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { 
     this.props.callback()
     Actions.pop() 
}}>
        <View>
            <Text style={s.text}>Group</Text>
        </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

This will:

1 - Dismiss the current light box

2 - Go to Home scene